# Quarkus Panache Mockito fails

Tags: mockito, junit5, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I struggle with mocking a Panache repository.
Here is the Entity:

```java
    import javax.persistence.*;
    
    @Entity
    public class Thing {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Simple repository:

```java
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepository;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ThingRepository implements PanacheRepository<Thing> {
}
```

This is the resource:

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/things")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ThingResource {

    @Inject
    ThingRepository thingRepository;

    @GET
    public List<Thing> list() {
        return thingRepository.listAll();
    }

}
```

and a simple test where I try to mock the repository:

```java
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@QuarkusTest
class ThingResourceTest {

    private Thing thing;

    @Inject ThingResource thingResource;
    @InjectMock ThingRepository thingRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        thing.setId(1L);
    }

    @Test
    void getAll() {
        List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
        things.add(thing);
        Mockito.when(thingRepository.listAll()).thenReturn(things);
        List<Thing> response = thingResource.list();
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertNotNull(response.get(0));
    }
}
```

The test fails because the response list is `<null>`.

The debugger tells me the `thingRepository` is actually mocked. But for some reason `Mockito.when().thenReturns()` does not return the list I set up.

[image]

What am I missing?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `thing` double declared. One time as class variable, and again in `setUp()`. Bummer. I apologize for the noise.